# Assigning variables to views

Tags: codeigniter, variables, view

what is the proper way of assigning variables to views?

```
$data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_all();
$this->load->view('users', $data);
// and inside users.php view: foreach($users as $user) {}
```

OR

```
$this->users = $this->users_model->get_all();
$this->load->view('users');
// and inside users.php view: foreach($this->users as $user) {}
```

Are there general rules for that type of situations?

Answer (score 5):

The first way is much better than the second and is the accepted way of passing variables to views.

For example, say you have two views.  The first view displays all users in the system and the second view displays the users that are currently logged in.  Both views loop over a `$users` variable and output their names.  Using your second method you would have to assign the appropriate data to `$this->users` before loading each view.  Having to use unique variable names between all loaded views for a given request would get out of hand.

Additionally, some views can become quite complex.  It wouldn't make any sense to assign each variable you need in a view to a property of your controller.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, that makes sense. Sounds like it's ok to use $this method for global variables (for example, config variables), if I understand correctly.

Comment: Donkeykong, I would hesitate before creating any additional properties to the "$this" global CI object. If you want to put configuration settings there I suggest you use /application/config/constants.php. In my project I have added a few properties to the CI controller ($this), including $data, $defaultLayout, and $displayView. These are related to passing data to the view, automatically loading the view, or applying layouts/templates.